# Passing radio button values to the controller

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have radio buttons that look like this

```
@foreach (ItemHasParts ihp in item.IHP)
{
    Part part = db.Parts.Find(ihp.PartID);
    string partID = part.ID.ToString();
    <tr>
        <td>
            @part.PartIDLink
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelPart => part.MFG_number)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelPart => part.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.RadioButton(partID, "Harvest")
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.RadioButton(partID, "Transfer")
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.RadioButton(partID, "Dispose")
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Here is my controller method

```cs
public ActionResult SpecialOrderSummary(JobOrder job, FormCollection form)
{
    //list of parts that were chosen to be transferred
    //list of parts that were chosen to be harvested
    //list of parts that were chosen to be disposed        
    return RedirectToAction("Details", "JobOrders", new { id = job.ID });
}
```

It loops through and generates the radio buttons for each part. How can I make my controller retrieve the values of each radio button that the user selected?

Comment: What're you returning to the view? What's your view model (or you have any)?

Comment: @DavidLiang I don't really have a view model for this scenario because I don't know how it would handle it. Any suggestion? I have a joborder model and a jodetails model that broke down the 'joborder' but that is setup for the regular joborder. What I'm doing is a different version of a job order so this transfer/dispose/harvest is an entirely new process

Comment: @DavidLiang actually I guess I can just use the JODetails view model that I have in place and can just adjust accordingly. I've added in my model to my question

Comment: The reason why you should have a view model being passed between the view and controller is that, beside all data necessary to display on the view, you can declare properties to contain user selections as well. So in your case, you can declare a list of selected parts for selected types. And it's not a good practice to pass your database model directly to a view anyway.

Comment: And the JODetails you just posted is not called view model. That's your database model, or your business model. The view doesn't need all the information to render. You're just revealing too much information to the view. It's better to just new up a view model and declare the only necessary properties you need to pass to the view.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help @DavidLiang  ! Would you be able to provide a brief example of how you would perform what I'm trying to do? I have been searching for a few hours now and I'm relatively new to all of this so any help would be awesome

Comment: I would love to provide you an example, but could you tell me more about what you want to capture on the form post in your OP? I see your view is looping through all the parts, but what are those "Harvest", "Transfer", etc, and what's the relationship between them and a part?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217334/discussion-between-josh-fontaine-and-david-liang).

Comment: @DavidLiang okay I provided more details in chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the best practice not to expose your back-end model to the view/front end. Instead, should you build a view model that only contains the data the view needs to render and pass it between the view and controller.

You can also declare additional properties in the view model to suite for what you need. In your case here, I can declare a property to contain the user selection for each part.

Let me show you what I mean.

First, I would convert the magic strings "Harvest", "Transfer" and "Dispose" to an enum because I don't like working on magic strings:

```cs
namespace DL.SO.RadiosToController.WebUI.Models.Item
{
    public enum PartActionType
    {
        Harvest,
        Transfer,
        Dispose
    }
}
```

And then you can craft out the view model(s) you need:

```cs
namespace DL.SO.RadiosToController.WebUI.Models.Item
{
    public class ItemViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string MFGNumber { get; set; }
        public IList<ItemPartViewModel> Parts { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class ItemPartViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public int PartId { get; set; }
        public string MFGNumber { get; set; }
        public string PartName { get; set; }

        // This is the additional property to contain what user picks
        public PartActionType SelectedActionType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

These view models as well as the enum should be in your controller model view by convention. Let's say you have an `ItemController` to display items as well as have methods to save the user selections on form post, these view models could be in the folder /Models/Item/.

And I just marked their IDs as required as I am guessing you need to IDs, on form post, to retrieve the data from the persistence storage.

And then you retrieve the data from your persistence storage, build the view model and return it to the view from the controller:

```cs
namespace DL.SO.RadiosToController.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class ItemController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            // Retrieve data from persistence storage and save it to the view model.
            // But here I am just faking it.
            var vm = new ItemViewModel
            {
                ItemId = 123,
                ItemName = "Fake Item",
                Parts = new List<ItemPartViewModel>
                {
                    new ItemPartViewModel
                    {
                        PartId = 1,
                        PartName = "Part 1"
                    },
                    new ItemPartViewModel
                    {
                        PartId = 2,
                        PartName = "Part 2"
                    },
                    new ItemPartViewModel
                    {
                        PartId = 3,
                        PartName = "Part 3"
                    },
                    new ItemPartViewModel
                    {
                        PartId = 4,
                        PartName = "Part 4"
                    }
                }
            };

            return View(vm);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Save(ItemViewModel model)
        {
            // Do what you need to do
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly you can construct the view:

```
<!-- 
    Here I create an alias for the namespace so that I don't have to type
    the long namespace every time.
-->
@using PartActionType = DL.SO.RadiosToController.WebUI.Models.Item.PartActionType

<!-- Here I declare the model for this view. -->
@model DL.SO.RadiosToController.WebUI.Models.Item.ItemViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Items";

    <!-- I am getting the enum values and assign them to this local variable -->
    var partActionTypes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(PartActionType));
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("save", "item", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ItemId)

    <table class="table table-sm text-center">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Item ID</th>
                <th>MFG ID</th>
                <th>Item Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>@Model.ItemId</td>
                <td>@Model.MFGNumber</td>
                <td>@Model.ItemName</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <h5>Parts In Items (@Model.Parts.Count)</h5>

    <table class="table table-sm text-center">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Part ID</th>
                <th>MFG ID</th>
                <th>Part Name</th>

                <!-- I'm displaying the names for the num dynamically. -->
                @foreach (var actionType in partActionTypes)
                {
                    <th>@Enum.GetName(typeof(PartActionType), actionType)</th>
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Parts.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Parts[i].PartId)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Parts[i].PartId)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Parts[i].MFGNumber)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Parts[i].MFGNumber)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Parts[i].PartName)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Parts[i].PartName)
                    </td>
                    @foreach (var actionType in partActionTypes)
                    {
                        <td>
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Parts[i].SelectedActionType, actionType)
                        </td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button>
}
```

One important thing to notice here is, to construct the part rows, instead of using the regular `@foreach()`, I have to use the regular for loop with index. The reason is when you use `@foreach()`, the name for those inputs would be the same, and when you post the inputs back to the server, the server won't see them as a list. You will have to use the regular for loop with an index so that the name of inputs will be different, and hence they're captured by the server as different item in the list:

```html
<input id="Parts_2__SelectedActionType" name="Parts[2].SelectedActionType" 
  type="radio" value="Transfer">
```

And you might have noticed those `@Html.HiddenFor()`. By default, the form will post any input back to the server. If you want to post additional data, you can use `@Html.HiddenFor()`, which will render as an hidden input.

[image]

[image]

On form post, you can see the correct radion button value is posted to the server.

**dotnet fiddle demo:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/wbGsbd

**Sample code in Github:** https://github.com/davidliang2008/DL.SO.RadiosToController